# UIButton is not highlighted when tap

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, highlight

I know there are lots of answer related to this topic but i try everything and simply not understand what is going wrong in the code. I simply add the button in top bar and try to tap but no highlight animation trigger.

See this video: http://sendvid.com/35e7za0p

Here is my code

```
if rightFisrtBtn != nil {
    btnfirst = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    btnfirst.tag = tagTopBar.btnfirst.rawValue
    btnfirst.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btnfirst.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    btnfirst.titleLabel?.font = fontWithSize


    if rightFisrtBtn! is String {
        btnfirst.setTitle(rightFisrtBtn as? String, for: .normal)
        btnfirst.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        btnfirst.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .highlighted)

        topView.addSubview(btnfirst)

        topView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[btnfirst(width)]-[btnSecond]", options: [], metrics: ["width":btnfirst.intrinsicContentSize.width + 10.0], views: ["btnfirst":btnfirst,"btnSecond":btnSecond]))

        topView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(25.0)-[btnfirst]-(gap)-|", options: [], metrics: ["gap":10.0], views: ["btnfirst":btnfirst]))

    } else if rightFisrtBtn! is UIImage {
        btnfirst.setImage(rightFisrtBtn as? UIImage, for: .normal)
        btnfirst.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.center
        topView.addSubview(btnfirst)

        topView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[btnfirst(width)]-[btnSecond]", options: [], metrics: ["width":btnfirst.imageView?.image?.size], views: ["btnfirst":btnfirst,"btnSecond":btnSecond]))

        topView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(25.0)-[btnfirst]-(gap)-|", options: [], metrics: ["gap":5.0], views: ["btnfirst":btnfirst]))
    }

    btnfirst.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTopbarFilter_Clicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

Comment: Use **btnfirst.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true** for highlight the touch.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma thanks for reply but I need default selected event which appear when there is image not TouchWhenHighlighted

Comment: "I simply add the button in top bar" That makes no sense. You cannot put a UIButton directly into a top bar. And I don't see any code where you do anything with `btnfirst`. Show how it gets into the interface, please.

Comment: @matt i am not using UINavigationBar. I made the topbar with view. Please watch video

Answer (score -1):

If i could understand your query, you want the attributes for the highlighted state of the button to appear when you tap the button.

In that case, in the implementation of target-action for the button use the  isSelected property of instance of UIButton :

func btnTopbarFilter_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
```

}